# The @state property doesn't initialization when the view open two times

Tags: swiftui

> Xcode 11 beta 6 , iOS Develop beta 8

I think that the @Satae property should be initialized, I don't know whether is the bug of the SwiftUI or I misunderstood the @State.

The operation flow is

1. Tap the Button(show another view) to open the another view.
2. Click the text field and input some data.
3. Tap the Button or drop down the view to close this view.
4. Tap the button(show another view) to open the another view.
5. You will find the text field has data, it doesn't initialize.

The code is like this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShow = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.isShow.toggle()}) {
            Text("show another view")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShow) {
            AnotherView()
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Input changing the @State property", text: $text)
            Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

The demo gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zitok.jpg

Comment: As @Fabian said this is part of what \@State is all about. Another way to fix this is to move text into ContentView and reset it in your Button. You can also use the sheet(item...) method and set text in the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@State` lives as long as it can and so is likely being reused between deconstructed views. But one can go around it in several ways.

#### Redrawing body only on first initialization due to part-`ObservableObject`

```
import SwiftUI

struct InitializeStateView: View {
    @State var isShow = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.isShow.toggle()}) {
            Text("show another view")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShow) {
            InitAnotherView()
        }
    }
}

class InitAnotherViewState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var wasInitialized = false
}

struct InitAnotherView: View {
    init() {
        print("Init InitAnotherView")
    }

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var state = InitAnotherViewState()
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        print("Redrawing InitAnotherView")

        if !state.wasInitialized {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                self.text = "hey"
            }
            state.wasInitialized = true
        }

        return VStack {
            TextField("Input changing the @State property", text: $text)
            Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

#### Redrawing body on every new character due to `ObservableObject`

```
import SwiftUI

struct InitializeStateView: View {
    @State var isShow = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.isShow.toggle()}) {
            Text("show another view")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isShow) {
            InitAnotherView()
        }
    }
}

class InitAnotherViewState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
    @Published var wasInitialized = false
}

struct InitAnotherView: View {
    init() {
        print("Init InitAnotherView")

    }

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var state = InitAnotherViewState()

    var body: some View {
        print("Redrawing InitAnotherView")

        return VStack {
            TextField("Input changing the @State property", text: $state.text)
            Button(action: {self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: It can work now, Thanks. Should @State property occupy memory space for long time? I assume that needs to be careful to use it.